# Is there a substitute for chocolate graham crackers?

Tags: substitutions, chocolate, crumb-crust, graham-crackers

Where I live, we don't have any kind of Graham crackers. I've used other cookies before instead of the regular Graham crackers without a problem. I now came across a recipe that asks for chocolate Graham cracker crumbs.

What do I do best?
Should I use a regular chocolate cookie? Add cacao powder to regular cookie crumbs? Something else?

Is there anything special about the chocolate Graham crackers?

FYI, I would need the crumbs for [this recipe](http://www.laurainthekitchen.com/recipes/banoffee-pie-parfait/).

Comment: You could try Oreo's if you have them in your area.

Comment: We have Oreos but they are quite expensive. We also have cheap knock-off Oreo-like cookies but they are not as nice.

Comment: You could make your own Oreo cookie (http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/oreo-cookies-recipe.html) or chocolate graham crackers (http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/chocolate-graham-crackers-recipe)

Comment: @JamesFlattery good suggestion and certainly useful in some cases. However, I don't want to put effort into making cookies and then destroying them ;-)

Comment: @Mien don't we all end up "destroying" our food with our teeth anyway? ;)

Answer (score 7):

If this had been a graham cracker crust, I'd have recommended adding some cocoa powder to the melted butter when making the crust.

In this case, as you're just using the crumbs in a layer of a parfait, you'd want the flavor to be better integrated as it doesn't have a chance to cook.  Therefore, I'd go with either crushed chocolate cookies or a mix of crushed graham crackers and chocolate shavings.  Both will give you the chocolate flavor and crunch at the same time.

You can also try working more chocolate flavor into some other ingredient (either with a chocolate liqueur or cocoa powder), but with something layered like this you often want the contrast of different flavors in each layer.

Comment: @Mien : that's why I said chocolate shavings in this case, not cocoa powder.

Comment: Sorry, was not reading carefully enough :) you are absolulely right so I deleted that comment

Comment: @Mien : as I missed that you had included the recipe, I think we're even.

Comment: Hahaha :D I agree!